# Aligning images in a list

Tags: html, css, image

I want my two images to be side by side so I used a list to inline them next to one and other, although I am unsure on how to move these images to the middle of the page while maintaining them to be side by side! Also should I be using a list or a div to get my images side by side?

[How my website looks currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDW2N.png)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Jacques Andre</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="banner">
        <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="##">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="###">About</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="mainlogo">Jacques André</div>
</div>

    <h1 id="favs">some of my favorites</h1>
        <ul class="images">
        <li><img id="paris" src="img/paris.jpeg" alt="paris"></li>
        <li><img id="naturalframe" src="img/naturalframe.JPG" alt="natural frame"></li>
        </ul> 
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    font-family: montserrat;
#favs{
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.images{
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
.images > li{
    display: inline-block;
}
#paris{
    width: 300px;
    height: 533.3px;
}
#naturalframe{
    width: 300px;
    height: 533.3px;
}
```

[Mock up of how I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLHHn.png)

Comment: If you create a minimal example instead of copy-pasting a lot of irrelevant code, you may get help earlier and in clearer way

Comment: Just edited! Sorry I forgot

Comment: Not really get your idea. But if you want align image in center of row. Add to CSS: `.image { text-align: center;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is make use of a `<div>` container for the images, and then simply have the `<img>` tags next to each other:

```
<div class="images">
  <img id="paris" src="img/paris.jpeg" alt="paris" />
  <img id="naturalframe" src="img/naturalframe.JPG" alt="natural frame" />
</div>
```

These should be `display: inline-block` (which is the *default* for images).

In order to centralise your `<img>` elements once you have them as siblings, all you need to do is give the parent container (`.images`) the rule `text-align: center`, which applies to inline elements. This may be a little counter-intuitive, as you're aligning *images* rather than text, but it works for all inline elements.

This can be seen in the following, which replaces your images with absolute links:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: montserrat;
  src: url('fonts/montserrat.otf')
}

body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  font-family: montserrat;
}

.nav {
  background-color: gray;
  color: black;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.nav>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}

.banner {
  background-color: #684848;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.mainlogo {
  color: white;
  font-size: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 300px;
}

#favs {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#paris {
  width: 300px;
  height: 533.3px;
}

#naturalframe {
  width: 300px;
  height: 533.3px;
}

.images {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jacques Andre</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="banner">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="##">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="###">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="mainlogo">Jacques André</div>
  </div>

  <h1 id="favs">some of my favorites</h1>
  <div class="images">
    <img id="paris" src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="paris" />
    <img id="naturalframe" src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="natural frame" />
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Note that if you were to have block-level elements, you would have to `float` them to the `left`, and vertically align them with `margin: 0 auto`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `text-align: center` in `.images`, like this:

```
.images{
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```